# How to remove % character from like clause in CodeIgniter Query Builder?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

In one of my **CodeIgniter** based application, I store the country data in a column as comma separated value [It is possible to pass multiple country from front-end and rather using another table as mapping (using foreign_key) I use one single table].

To fetch the result in a search page, I wrote the following query:

```
$this->db->like('country', $country_id);
```

What the problem I face is, suppose **row_1** contains the following data for my target column: **1,3,17** and now if I pass **$country_id = 7**, it fetches **row_1**, although **row_1** does not directly have 7 (but have 17)...

I know that the problem occurs as **CodeIgniter** converts my query as **%7%**.

So my question: Is there any way to omit % character from before and after the search_creteria in **CodeIgniter**?

I mean, **CodeIgniter** will convert my query as:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE country LIKE '7'
```

rather (what is currently do):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE country LIKE '%7%'
```

- Thanks

Comment: The answer is to restructure your table where you don't have a comma separated list of values in a single cell (You should never really need this anyways, there is almost always a better way to do that), or fetch just like you are right now and loop through the results to check if it's a true match

Comment: Try `$this->db->like('country', $country_id, 'none');` to remove the wildcards although it won't do what you intend it to do, GrumpyCrouton is correct.